# normalize-space() not working

Tags: xslt-2.0

**Input :**

```
<article-id pub-id-type="doi">10.13031/aim.20152184755 </article-id>

<article-id pub-id-type="publisher-id">152184755 </article-id>

<article-id pub-id-type="other">Copyright</article-id>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('localfile:', 
  normalize-space(//article-id[@pub-id-type='publisher-id']), '.pdf')">
```

**output:**

`xlink:href="localfile:152184755 .pdf` (before . space also coming)

**Required output:**

```
xlink:href="localfile:152184755.pdf
```

I want to remove space from output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post a [mcve] and use proper code formatting (see `{ }` button).

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. With Saxon 9.7 I get the expected output of `localfile:152184755.pdf`. Please give more details about how you are running the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your guide.. it was not actually space. its a junk character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could that space actually be a non-breaking spacing? Check the file with a hex editor (such as [HHD Software's free-hex-editor](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor)) to see if its a #160 (xA0) under the covers.

Comment: Thanks for your guide.. it was not actually space. its a junk character